# doseq over a simple lazy seq runs out of heap space

Tags: clojure, lazy-sequences

When stress-testing some Clojure code at work, I noticed it runs out of heap space when iterating over large data-sets. I eventually managed to trace the issues back to the combination of Clojure's `doseq` function, and implementation fo lazy sequences.

This is the minimal code snippet that crashes Clojure by exhausting available heap space:

```
(doseq [e (take 1000000000 (iterate inc 1))] (identity e))
```

The documentation for `doseq` clearly states that it doesn't retain the head of the lazy sequence, so I would expect the memory complexity of the above code to be close to O(1). Is there something I'm missing? What's the Clojure-idiomatic way of iterating over extremely large lazy sequences, if `doseq` isn't up to the job?

Comment: Which clojure version and java runtime are you using? Running that code in a clean repl with clojure 1.4 / java 1.6.0_33 on OSX shows completely static memory use at just under 400 Mb

Comment: Are you sure that's the exact snippet which is causing the problem? Runs fine on my machine (Clojure 1.4, JDK7, Windows, Eclipse/CCW). It *would* be a problem if you held onto the head of the sequence somehow, e.g. if (iterate inc 1) was stored somewhere else.

Comment: You're both right, the problem goes away when I turn off the things Leiningen 2 adds to the REPL (history, key navigation, etc.) and just use the vanilla Clojure 1.4. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

When I run this sample I see the memory usage hit 2.0 Gigs so perhaps you are actually just running out of ram.

it sure does take a while to run:

```
user=> (time (doseq [e (take 1000000000 (iterate inc 1))] (identity e)))
"Elapsed time: 266396.221132 msecs"
```

form top:

```
23999 arthur    20   0 4001m 1.2g 5932 S  213 15.3  17:11.35 java                                          
24017 arthur    20   0 3721m 740m 5548 S   88  9.3  13:49.95 java
```